# How can I make an alias on yii SQL statement using relationships?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm trying to associate two tables using the following code on Yii:

```
$this->stocks= $stocks->find()->select(['id', 'type.name'])->joinWith('stockType type')->where(['fk_product' => $productId, 'fk_product_type' => 'type.id'])->all();
```

The problem is: I want the stocks ID and i'm geting an error saying the ID is ambiguous:

> 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

So, how can I name the table $stocks or make it an alias so that I can remove the ambiguity?

Thanks!

Comment: try getting id with table name for eg:- type.id

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But is there a way to make an alias for this table?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/42791-how-do-i-refer-to-the-table-alias-of-a-relation-in-its-on-property/ //try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `StocksModel` is the prototype-class of `$stocks`, you can do as below.

```
$socksTableName = StocksModel::tableName();

$this->stocks= StocksModel::find()
    ->select([$socksTableName . '.id', 'type.name'])
    ->joinWith('stockType type')
    ->where([
        'fk_product' => $productId,
        'fk_product_type' => 'type.id'
    ])
    ->all();
```